# How to get controller object in repository class in symfony2

Tags: symfony

How to use "NotFoundException" in repository class in Symfony2?

```
$test = $em->getRepository('DemoBundle:Test')->find(1);

if (!$test) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('The category area does not exist. Id 1');
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make this in your controler action ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to throw **an appropriate** exception **(in/inside/within)** your Repository when your query has no result. Then you should use [Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.NoResultException.html).

By the way, the code snippet you shared should not be used in your repository.

Comment: From the docs, here is a code example: 
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT ...')
    ->setMaxResults(1);

try {
    $product = $query->getSingleResult();
} catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
    $product = null;
}

Answer (score 1):

Another way for error handling use session error like

```
try {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('product')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                $this->get('session')->setFlash('warning', 'Unable to find Product.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->setFlash('success', 'Product Detail has been deleted.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_products'));
        } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
            $this->get('session')->setFlash(
                    'warning', 'This Product cannot be deleted!'
            );
            return $this->redirect($this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer'));
        }
    }
```

And on your twig template use below given code.

```
{% if app.session.hasFlash('success') %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">   
    {{ app.session.flash('success') }}
        </div>

{% endif %}
    {% if app.session.hasFlash('warning') %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">   
    {{ app.session.flash('warning') }}
            </div>

{% endif %}
```